# How to make a spatial plot within desired level of values of a variable from netcdf file using matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, netcdf, levels

I could able to interpolate and plot chlorophyll concentration with respective x ,y. Now I need to display within a specific range of values. For example value between 0 and 10 as in the code below

```
ncfile_1 = 'A20150322015059.L3m_MO_CHL_chlor_a_4km.nc';
lat_1 = ncread(ncfile_1,'lat') ;
lon_1 = ncread(ncfile_1,'lon') ;
chlor_a_1 = ncread(ncfile_1,'chlor_a');
[X_1,Y_1] = meshgrid(lon_1,lat_1) ;
xi_1 = linspace(30,100,1000) ;
yi_1 = linspace(0,30,1000) ;
[Xi_1,Yi_1] = meshgrid(xi_1,yi_1);
iwant_1 = interp2(X_1,Y_1,chlor_a_1',Xi_1,Yi_1)' ;
pcolor(xi_1,yi_1,iwant_1'); shading interp;
c = colorbar;
cmap = jet(255);
cmap(:,3) = 0;
colormap(cmap)
caxis([0, 10])
```

I could plot figure but the levels in the plot seems wrong. Please point out the mistake in my code.

I have tried with this code but doesn't work

```
if chlor_a_1>=0 && chlor_a_1<=10
disp(chlor_a_1);
[Xi_1,Yi_1,chlor_a_1] = peaks;
plot(Xi_1,Yi_1,chlor_a_1,49)
```

I am a beginner on Matlab. Any help is highly appreciated.